# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException - Web Socket

Tags: websocket, networkonmainthread

I am testing chatting service with "Web socket"

The code doesn't make any error. But, when I lunch the app, it even cannot be started with

the error

```
06-10 16:59:22.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10814): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-10 16:59:22.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10814): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.websocketchat_test/com.websocketchat_test.WebsocketChat}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-10 16:59:22.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10814):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2466)
06-10 16:59:22.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10814):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
06-10 16:59:22.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10814):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2008)
06-10 16:59:22.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10814):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-10 16:59:22.420: E/AndroidRuntime(10814):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1169)
```

My main code is here..

```
public class WebsocketChat extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

private static String SERVER_HOST = "10.0.0.1";

private WebSocket websocket;
private EditText messageEditText;
private TextView logsTextView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    messageEditText = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
    logsTextView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.logsTextView);

    try {
        URI url  = new URI("ws://" + SERVER_HOST + "/");
        websocket = new WebSocketConnection(url);

        websocket.setEventHandler(new WebSocketEventHandler() {
            Handler handler = new Handler();

            public void onOpen() {
                updateLog("connected.");
            }

            public void onMessage(final WebSocketMessage message) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        updateLog(message.getText().trim());
                    }
                });
            }

            public void onClose() {
                updateLog("closed");
            }
        });

        View sendButton = this.findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    } catch (WebSocketException wse) {
        wse.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException use) {
        use.printStackTrace();
    }
} 

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    try {
        websocket.connect();
    } catch (WebSocketException wse) {
        wse.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    try {
        websocket.send(messageEditText.getText().toString());
        messageEditText.setText("");
    } catch (WebSocketException wse) {
        wse.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void updateLog(String message) {
    logsTextView.setText("> " + message + "\n" + logsTextView.getText());
}
```

}

I don't know why it's happened. I added internet permission for sure..
Any suggestion would be OK. Reply it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent Android version won't allow *any* network activity on your main/UI thread. You might have a look at [AutobahnAndroid](http://www.autobahn.ws/android) - an Android/Java WebSocket implementation that does all networking on background threads.

Disclosure: I am original author of Autobahn and work for Tavendo.

Comment: hello. I accessed the website...but..is there any example of chatting with using websocket?

Comment: I want to download Echoclient in Github..but i can't...could you please send me the file with my mail?

Comment: You can clone the Git repo or download a zipped archive from https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid/archive/master.zip.

Comment: The closest to a chat demo is the following: https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid/tree/master/Demo/SimplePubSub

Comment: i don't know how to use example....trying to install node.js..but not working!!!!!! Btw, isn't it possible to use a code above after modifying??

Comment: There is a getting started here http://autobahn.ws/android/getstarted, and further tutorials here http://autobahn.ws/android/tutorials

Comment: i want to connect between android device and web with using websocket. is that tutorial for this case?

Comment: actually, I followed your tutorial! but there were problems!

Comment: there says, "start a websocket echo server on some host and adjust line 18for the ip of the host" But, i don't know which server do i need to install. node.js is ok?

Comment: @obserstet your tutorial is not working..I added a project with eclipse..and ran it..but couldnt see the log what you expected